# PLS-00201: identifier 'IMMEDIATE' must be declared when using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to use execute immediate to create a table as follows :

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (q'{CREATE TABLE ... ;}');
```

However oracle gives me the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'IMMEDIATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

how do i correctly format my string to create my table?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run ddl operation using dynamic sql with sqlplus.

Test case to replicate the error

```
   SQL> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (q'{CREATE TABLE test1000(id int,name varchar2(10)}');
    BEGIN IMMEDIATE (q'{CREATE TABLE test1000(id int,name varchar2(10)}';); END;
    
          *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PLS-00201: identifier 'IMMEDIATE' must be declared
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Since it doesn't work in sqlplus let's switch to anonymous pl/sql block

```
  SQL> BEGIN
  2   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (q'{CREATE TABLE test1000(id int,name varchar2(10));}');
  3* END;
SQL> /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Remove colon in curly brackets to avoid above error

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (q'{CREATE TABLE test1000(id int,name varchar2(10))}');
  3* END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> @ddl test1000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,OWNER)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "HR"."TEST1000"
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0),
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(10) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP"
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP" SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE" ;
```